# Why is my ul CSS working in IE but not Chrome?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

As the title says; this seems to work fine on Internet Explorer, but not on Chrome (the formatting doesn't show up on Chrome and is just plain, as if the CSS isn't being applied). I'm unsure why as it seems to work alright if I put the css inside the head tag straight in the html (however I need it in the CSS for other reasons).

Any help would be appreciated :)

This is a snippet from my html:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newcss.css">
</head>
<body>

<ul class="sidenav">
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

And this is a snippet from my CSS:

```
ul.sidenav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

ul.sidenav li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.sidenav li a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

ul.sidenav li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}

div.content {
    margin-left: 25%;
    padding: 1px 16px;
    height: 1000px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    ul.sidenav {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        position: relative;
    }
    ul.sidenav li a {
        float: left;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    div.content {margin-left: 0;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    ul.sidenav li a {
        text-align: center;
        float: none;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please define 'not working' and perhaps show us how it should actually look versus how it actually is.

Comment: Also, you are styling a `ul` where as there is no `ul` in your DOM. Change the div to a ul and try.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain to well the first time and uploaded the wrong code!

Comment: I added your code to a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bywhj5de/ and then ran the fiddle in chrome/ie/edge and they all looked the same to me...

Comment: What does Chrome console say when you load the page?  Have you tried inspecting the elements in the page using dev. tools (F12 in Chrome)?

Answer (score 0):

So not sure why that was happening, but I uninstalled then reinstalled Chrome and it worked?

Oh well